# Why was the question on the history of $y=y(x)$ put on hold?

Tags: discussion

It seems that we are still accepting questions on the history of mathematics as well as on notation. Why was [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252928/when-did-the-abuse-of-notation-y-yx-start) not considered to be of research level on these two tags? I have checked the help center and can't find an answer there.

Comment: The comments seemed to be taking the thread way off course.  In particular, Carlo's comment (the very first) was an excellent answer.  Your original question can likely be answered, but I doubt it will be any more useful than Carlo's.

Comment: @RyanBudney I agree that the comments and answers (except for the first few by Mauro Allegranzas) were taking the tread off track. But this also applies to Carlos comment: I was not asking for ways to interpret the notation, nor did I want to discuss its pros & cons. So his comment does not answer the question. I wanted to know if it is possible to identify an early source who startet this. I added a clarification before it was put on hold, but seemingly that was not enough.

Comment: Having looked at hsm.stackexchange for the first time right now, I'm thinking it might be better to take such a question there. But that makes me wonder if MO should not generally discourage all history questions on its site from now on.

Comment: The existence of hsm.SE notwithstanding, questions on history of mathematics *are* on-topic on MO.

Comment: On-topicness of questions on history of mathematics on MO notwithstanding, I notice that people who raise such questions are often referred to hsm.SE.

Answer (score 4):

I have cast a final vote to reopen, but: I would encourage users to give History of Science and Mathematics a try in cases like this. (It is in danger of becoming moribund, which I think would be a shame, as there are real experts who have contributed there.)

Michael, if you do not receive answers that answer the question you asked to your satisfaction and in a reasonable amount of time, then please consider flagging the question to request migration to HSM. I notice that Franz Lemmermeyer, who seems to be knowledgeable about history, was one of the closers; perhaps he'd prefer to answer you there (?).

Comment: Thanks Todd. Will do so.

Comment: Could downvoters please shed light on what they find unsatisfactory?